# Can review rate app after delete and reinstall of the app iOS

Tags: appirater

I gone through the appirater sdk(iOS) on git, I have question.
If i rated the app and then i deleted the app from device and again installed. In this case will appirater allows to rate again ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in that case Appirater will prompt the user to rate the app again.

The data about whether or not the user has rated the app is only stored locally, so deleting the app deletes that info.

Comment: Thanks Arash ... one more question  ---  once rated the app on app store and without deleting does it allows me to rate again ?

Comment: Yes, whenever the app's version number changes (e.g. when it is updated), Appirater will ask the user for another review.